# I've already recorded my iphone video at a non-ideal zoom - anything I can do to make the best of the situation?

Tags: scale, iphone, zoom

Sorry I know nothing about cameras/recording. I'd like to maximize the video-quality given my current situation, and also appreciate any basic tips for next time!

I have an iPhone 14, and I recorded some overhead footage of piano-playing, at 0.5x zoom. The problem at the time was that 1x zoom was slightly too zoomed in, so I made it 0.5x zoom when recording. In hindsight, I feel I should have manually zoomed in to about 0.9x or something (am I right about this, or does it not even matter?).

So now I have a 0.5x zoom HDR video, and I want to edit it in a video-editor, and I would like to know what's the best I can do to improve the situation. Should I edit the video's zoom on my iPhone before giving it to my video-editor? Or is that the same effect as zooming it in my video-editor?